# How to fix streched texture areas after unwraping UVs?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I just UV unwrapped my first model and I have a problem with the texture. The UV unwrap looks fine (all blue), but in the 3d model it's not that good. The texture stretches and I'm not sure why. I'm using Blender 2.80.

[image]

Comment: It's probably because of modifiers you have in stack on the object. If there are faces with more than 5 sides they might cause deformations after e.g. subdivision. Hard to say without more information about mesh topology and modifiers used

Comment: i only use a subdivision modifier,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the solution by myself, i added a loop cut (ctrl + r) where the texture stretches.[image]